# The woman, the killer and the husband

Tags: logical-deduction

Detective Rajmohan was jogging on an early morning. On his way, he found a crowd around a dead body of a woman.

People were staring at the strange body with fear.

Rajmohan took the mobile phone from the jeans pocket of the dead body and he dialed the last number, saved as " My Hus". On the other end, someone answered. Their conversation was like this:

> Rajmohan: Hello, can you come? Your wife is lying dead in the middle of the road!
>
> *My Hus*: What? Yes, I am coming!

Within 5 minutes, the husband was here. He arrived alone in a car.
But the detective arrested him without asking or saying a word.

Why?

Comment: I think the same question was asked here in puzzling.SE before more than 1 time

Comment: @AeJey  I do think the same, as it is a known logic riddle.

Comment: But I don't see any now. May be removed by marking as plagiarism.

Comment: Please DONT over edit the conversation.It should contain some mystery.

Comment: The mystery is still safe, don't worry. On the other hand, please [read this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question, as it can help you to better format your future puzzles.

Comment: I would like to point to this as well: [Clarification of the "logical-deduction" tag](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/logical-deduction/info)

Answer (score 5):

It is because:

> The detective doesn't give a precise adress, but the husband still know where to come.

Comment: right Congratulations

Comment: ouch, i was occupied by editting and too late for answer

Comment: Wow that was quick

Comment: Areeb, it was quick because it's a very easy puzzle (and also a well-known one -- see the remark in comments above about its being a duplicate, and note that the earlier one was also answered within a couple of minutes of being posted).

Comment: Hey guys, this isn't 1999 anymore. https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/find-my-friends/id466122094?mt=8